# Java formatting, negative values, zero padding

Tags: java, string, format

Here's a quote from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

> 'd'   '\u0054'    Formats the argument as a decimal integer. The
>   localization algorithm is applied.
>
> If the '0' flag is given and the value is negative, then the zero padding will occur after the sign.

I feel frustrated, trying to learn this formatting thing but that tutorial is just so cluttered and messy.

```
String.format("%03d", int);
```

I am trying to understand where exactly this whole \u0054 should go but I have just no idea, I must be missing something very obvious or something...

Edit:

**What I want to achieve: 
Positive 10: 010 
Negative 10: -10
Negative result I want to achieve: -010**

Comment: `'\u0054'` is equivalent to `'d'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\u0054` is `d`

You can do

```
((i < 0) ? "-" : "") + String.format("%03d", Math.abs(i));
```

Comment: If I just keep it the way I have now, the negative (-) replaces a zero so: positive 10: 010 for example, but the negative would be -10 but I want it to say -010

Comment: @Deragon something close which maintains consistency should be `"%+04d"` which will produce `"+010"` and `"-010"`.

Answer (score 7):

Try `String.format("% 4d", i)` then (with a space between % and 4); it's using 4 positions, zero-padded and it leaves an extra space for positive values, so you get " 010" and "-010". You can `trim()` the string afterwards to get rid of the initial space (or do something like `if (i>0) s=s.substring(1)` or something).

Comment: I like this answer.  It gives proper padding for non-negative values.  You need a "% 04d" to maintain the proper number of leading zeros, though.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `String.format("% 04d", i)`?

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = -13754;
        int p = 2234;
        String buffer = String.format("%08d", n);
        System.out.println(buffer);
        buffer = String.format("%08d", p);
        System.out.println(buffer);
    }
}
```

output

```
-0013754
00002234
```

For your example   "%03d" is what you would use.